# Problems loading Textures in SFML (C++)

Tags: c++, sfml

I started using SFML recently and I was doing well until I got to textures. Every time I use .loadFromFile it make the execution break with the exception:

```
    Exception thrown at 0x6E18DC07 (vcruntime140.dll) in SFML Vertex 
    Arrrays.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00EA3000.
```

I have looked at other threads and most of them say that there is a problem that your mixing debug and release, but I'm not otherwise I wouldn't be asking the question. Any solutions?
(I'm using SFML 2.3 with Visual Studio 2015)

Comment: Do you have the .dll files in the right location?  Have you tried running your program as an administrator?

Comment: Yes, I have the .dll files where they should be. No I haven't tried running it as an administrator (though I don't see how that'd help).

Comment: Since you don't understand the problem, you can't really judge a solution. I would also try different compilers to narrow the problem.